# SIlverstripe check page name in .ss file

Tags: templates, silverstripe

I want to check – in the template .ss file – the page name or title in order to show a different image. I'd like to do something like that:

```
<% if $SiteConfig.Title == 'video' %> 
   <img src="themes/blackcandy/images/image.jpg" /> 
<% else if $SiteConfig.Title == 'bio' %> 
   <img src="themes/blackcandy/images/image1.jpg" /> 
... 
...

<% end_if %>
```

The code above of course doesn't work. How do I do it? Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Thanks a lot.
Mauro

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check it throu the title use $Title (without the SiteConfig controller)?

```
<% if $Title == 'video' %> 
   <img src="themes/blackcandy/images/image.jpg" /> 
<% else if $Title == 'bio' %> 
   <img src="themes/blackcandy/images/image1.jpg" />
<% end_if %>
```

If you want to check PageType use ClassName

```
<% if ClassName = PageType1 %>
    <img src="themes/blackcandy/images/image1.jpg" /> 
<% end_if %>
```

If you want to check throu Url use UrlSegment (see Clints answer)

Answer (score 2):

It's best to use URLSegment for this.

```
<% if URLSegment = video %>
    <img src="themes/blackcandy/images/video-image.jpg" />
<% else_if URLSegment = bio %>
    <img src="themes/blackcandy/images/bio-image.jpg" />
<% end_if %>
```

Thanks to banal at: http://www.silverstripe.org/themes-2/show/11325

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're on silverstripe 2.4:

```
<% control SiteConfig %>
  <% if Title = video %>
    video
  <% else_if Title = bio %>
    bio
  <% end_if %>
<% end_control %>
```

note not to put quotes around the values (bio instead of 'bio').
i supposed the following to be valid too:

```
<% if SiteConfig.Title = bio %>
```

but for some reason it doesn't work - not sure about this.

Comment: Thanks for that. it doesn't give any error but it doesn't return anything neither. The HTML that it supposed to show if the condition is satisfied it's just not there. And yes I'm on SS 2.4. Any idea why?

Comment: sure you put the corresponding value in the Title field in the CMS (e.g. no whitespace added)? added '?flush=All' to the url?